# Samba Domain Controller corrupts Windows workstations profiles?

Tags: windows-xp, samba, mac-osx-server

Oooooook, so here's my problem.

I have a Mac OS X Server 10.5 to which Windows XP workstations are bound. I happened upon some errors and warnings in my log, from Userenv. Namely, error 1504, 1509.

The warning complains that some setting on the share about offline caching. I found some guides to correct this if the problem was referring to a Windows server, but since those are Samba shares, the guide of course doesn't apply.

Does anyone know what to do so that my profiles don't corrupt, and I still can use roaming profiles so that they're backed up by the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Native (Windows-server-based) roaming profiles are hit-and-miss.  Many setups work fine, but I've also seen them implode for no apparent reason.  So given that the "baseline" (using a Windows Server for storing the profile) implies some potential issues, don't immediately chalk it up to using Samba.
2. [Samba has very specific settings for the use and support of profiles.  Have you had a chance to read their documentation at the official website for clues to a solution?](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/ProfileMgmt.html)

Comment: No, I didn't think to take the problem from that perspective. I was stuck in my "Mac OS X Server" point of view, but this looks promising.

Comment: The settings covered by the second link do not answer to my problem, sadly. I'll continue to look up on the official samba site.